How to use median as the reduction function for loss in Pytorch Lightning Trainer?
I want to log the median loss every epoch in Pytorch Lightning. I tried self.log(..., reduce_fx=torch.median) which gave me error lightning_fabric.utilities.exceptions.MisconfigurationException: Only `self.log(..., reduce_fx={min,max,mean,sum})` are supported. If you need a custom reduction, please log a `torchmetrics.Metric` instance instead. Found: <function median at 0x7f53bbd59fc0>
So I implement a subclass of torchmetrics.Metric, and pass that as reduce_fx:
import torch
from torchmetrics import Metric

class MedianMetric(Metric):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_state("median", default=torch.Tensor(0))
    
    def update(self, batch_losses):
        self.median = torch.median(self._input_format(batch_losses))

    def compute(self):
        return self.median.float()
    
    def __name__(self):
        return "median"

in my LightningModule:
class MyModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self._red = MedianMetric()
        ...
    ...
    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        loss, _ = self.calculate_metrics_and_loss(batch, batch_idx, metric=False)
        self.log("train_loss", loss, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, reduce_fx=self._red)
        return loss

Now I get TypeError: MedianMetric.update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. I think it wants me to put preds and inputs as the arguments to update, but then I'm re-calculating the loss once in training_step and then a second time in MedianMetric.compute, which doesn't seem right. Is there an easy way to keep track of median loss per epoch using Lightning?

post the code with the call to update(). We can't see that call so we have no idea what you're actually passing to it

@DerekG I don't call update() myself - it is from Lightning's callback when I call self.log in training_step. I will show the trace.

I could not figure out a way to do it with self.log in training_step. However you can aggregate them yourself.
def MyModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self._training_batch_losses = []

    ...

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        # get batch loss
        ...
        self._training_batch_losses.append(batch_loss)
        return batch_loss

    def on_train_epoch_end(self):
        epoch_median = torch.stack(self._training_batch_losses).median()
        self.log("train_loss_epoch", epoch_median)
        self._training_batch_losses.clear()

It works for validation as well.
